# Display Membership type description on contribution page?

Tags: civimember, contribution-page

Can't seem to find the answer but sure there must be a simple way to achieve what I need.

On the contribution pages for Civi I would like to show the membership type description for the various membership types that need further explanation to users.

Is there a easy way to enable this or do I need to look at a more custom route?

Thanks in advance for any pointers!

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to achieve the above using Offline membership ? If so then add the source while creating the membership (membership source)

Comment: @Ramesh-ARTECHConsultancy Thanks for the reply, I mean on the contribution signup pages themselves? I've added a picture as an example to show what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the header and footer would allow me to put description above and below it wasn't exactly what I needed.

The best solution for me was leveraging the use of the Civicrm webform integration and adding the required mark up and form alters where I required them to achieve the required display.

Answer (score 2):

If you did this as a Price Set you would be able to have some info in the post-field-help, and you can set the 'label' to be different to the membership type if you want eg

[image]

and actually the Price Options do have a pre/post help options but they show inline, presumably some minor theming could address that

[image]

Currently at https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/price/field?reset=1&action=browse&sid=10&new=1 but will be flushed within 24 hours

Comment: Thanks, this works nicely also :).

Answer (score 1):

You could certainly put an explanation of the types in the introduction text box which is displayed immediately above the price set